# How to loop through all unchecked checkboxes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

Using jQuery, is there a fast way to loop through all **unchecked** checkboxes on a page that have **className="carCheckboxes"**.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use the `.each()` method with the `:not(:checked)` selector.  Here are the references:

[Reference to jQuery.each method](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/)

[Reference to jQuery:not selector](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/)

[Reference to jQuery:checked selector](http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/)

```
$("input.carCheckboxes:not(:checked)").each (function () {
  //your code to loop through each element.
  //$(this) references the current element as a jQuery Object
});
```